# How do you exit from an Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

How do you exit from an `invoke-command` script block running on a remote server? I have tried `next`.

Here is my code:

```
$Res = Invoke-Command -Session $Ses -ArgumentList ($ROOTdir, $PARAMS.SYS, $PARAMS.main, $PARAMS.zip) -ScriptBlock {
    Param($ROOTdir, $SYS, $MAIN, $ZIP)
    $list | %{
        $completed = $false
        $retrycount = 1
        while (-not $completed) {
            try {
                $Copytime = (Measure-Command {
                    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination ($SYS.KITCHENdir) -Force -ErrorVariable copyerror
                }).TotalSeconds
                $completed = $true
            } catch {
                if ($retrycount -gt $MAIN.Retry ) {
                    break or exit #HOW STOP EXECUTING NEXT STEPS AND EXIT
                } else {
                    Start-Sleep $MAIN.DelayRetry
                    $retrycount++
                }
            }
        }
        #IF copy bad result need stop and exit
        #The final one can produce flavors here, but it does not look quite kosher
        #next steps
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to use the `Exit` keyword.

> "The exit keyword is used to exit from contexts; it will exit the
>   (currently running) context where your code is running. This means
>   that if you use this keyword in a script, and launch the script
>   directly from your console, it will exit both the script and the
>   console since they're both running in the same context. However, if
>   you use the exit keyword in a function within the script, and call
>   that function from the same script, it will just exit the script and
>   not the entire console. The exit keyword is best used in functions,
>   and when those functions are called in a script. It's a great way to
>   terminate execution of functions."
>
> - https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/powershell-terminating-code-execution